How can I play a video directly from a USB flash drive on my iPhone, without having to transfer first the entire video from the flash drive to iPhone?
I have a USB flash drive that contains a video file. I'd like to view it on my iPhone. The USB flash drive  is connected to my iPhone.
I know I can open the video by browsing the USB flash drive with the Files application, then share the video to my video player (VLC). However, doing so causes the video to be fully transferred from the USB flash drive to the iPhone before the video starts playing. I don't want to wait for the transfer to complete: instead, I'd like the video to start playing before the transfer is complete.
How can I play a video directly from a USB flash drive on my iPhone, without having to transfer the entire video from the flash drive to the iPhone?

You can use the VLC Player app.
I use it all the time on my iPhone 15 with a drive connected via USB-C
